# Fancybox iframe with header ajax (X-Requested-With) without using ajax type

Tags: jquery, ajax, iframe, header, fancybox-2

I have a common function to open internal pages in iframe via Fancybox:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">

        $(document).ready(function() {

            // Fancybox
            $(".iframe-page-no-refresh").fancybox({
                padding     : 5,
                width       : 1024,
                height      : 768,
                minWidth    : 1280,
                minHeight   : 720,
                maxWidth    : 1280,
                maxHeight   : 720,
                fitToView   : false,
                width       : '50%',
                height      : '70%',
                autoSize    : true,
                closeClick  : false,
                openEffect  : 'none',
                closeEffect : 'none',
                iframe      : {
                    scrolling : 'auto',
                    preload   : true,
                    cache   : false,
                },
                beforeLoad     : function () {iframe_header($(this).attr('href'))}, // Before loading
                afterLoad     : function () {iframe_header($(this).attr('href'))}, // After loading
                beforeShow     : function () {iframe_header($(this).attr('href'))}, // Before changing in current item
                afterShow     : function () {iframe_header($(this).attr('href'))}, // After opening
                // afterClose    : function() {} // After close
            });

            function iframe_header(url){
                $.ajax({
                    url: 'http://localhost/test.php',
                    headers: {'X-Requested-With': 'XMLHttpRequest'}
                }); 
            }

        });

    </script>
```

To open a page I use the following link:

```
 <a data-fancybox-type="iframe" href="http://localhost/test.php" class="iframe-page-no-refresh">Test</a>
```

I wish I could say that the current page (in the iframe) is the ajax changing the header even if the page in the iframe is identical to the current page.
As if the type was defined ajax:

```
 headers  : { 'X-fancyBox': true }
```

Current page included in a fancybox iframe must indicate that the header is ajax.